# Linear Mixed Effects Models - combining coefficients

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Suppose I have a sample of height data for a population with sex and region identifiers. Now, suppose I estimated the linear mixed model against a variable $x$. I'm using the `lme4` package in R to estimate a linear mixed model, so in R-speak:

```
height ~ x + (1 | sex) + (1 | region)
```

Would it be possible to combine the mixed effect coefficients to extract the equation for all males in the US? How would you go about this?

Assuming it's possible, would it be the same procedure if I had a mixed effect slope as well?

```
height ~ x + (1 + x | sex) + (1 + x | region)
```

Comment: I don't know if this changes your question, but it is almost certainly not practical to use `sex` (which presumably only two levels, unless you are either dealing with a fungal population or confusing gender and sex and allowing many genders ...) as a random effect. `~x + sex + (1|region)`, or `~x*sex+(x|region)`, is much more sensible. `ranef()`, or `coef()`, is how you extract the group-specific coefficients

Comment: Hi Ben, that's for your comments. What's the difference between `ranef ` and `coef`? And out of curiosity, why is it not practical to use `sex` as a random effect?